# Can't get any packages to work with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-5, laravel-mix

I can't figure out how to include JavaScript packages in my Laravel project. I've been trying to install packages, and I can't figure out how it works. For example: Let's say I want to install Bootstrap Confirmation (http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/).

I install it from my project root folder.

```
$ npm install bootstrap-confirmation2
```

After that, the package.json file looks like the following.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/bootbox": "^4.4.36",
        "bootbox": "^5.1.2",
        "bootstrap-confirmation2": "^4.1.0"
    }
}
```

I then add the package to app.js.

```
require('bootstrap-confirmation2');
```

And my webpack.mix.js looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

After that, I run this from my console:

```
npm run dev
```

If I try to use my Bootstrap confirmation package it doesn't work, no errors, nothing.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="confirmation">Confirmation</button>
```

I know the problem is not in the package but in the way I try to install packages and including them in my app.js file that is loaded once I open the app.

I checked the 'Network' tab in Chrome dev tools, checked that 'app.js' is loaded, searched the file and the package I installed and included is INSIDE the JS file and it still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the terminal, run the following install.

```
npm install bootstrap-confirmation2
```

The **package.json** should now look something like the following. Dependencies are jQuery, Popper.js (for Bootstrap 4), and of course, Bootstrap 4.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-confirmation2": "^4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.15",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0"
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**app.css**

```
// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

**app.js**

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    
    require('bootstrap');
    require('bootstrap-confirmation2');
} catch (e) {}
```

**In your Blade template/layout:**

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="confirmation" data-title="Open Google?"
    href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Confirmation</a>
```

At the end of the file, after the closing body tag:

```
</body>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

In app.js...

```
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
    rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
    // other options
});
```

At the terminal:

```
npm run prod
```

[image: Screenshot]

I hope that helped.

Comment: You are the man! Thx. Now I know how to install another package from npm, for example `npm install bootstrap-show-password`. I just want to point out that the file `app.js`is rather the `resources/js/bootstrap.js`